subgroup relations between centers, centralizers, and normalizers
I am reading abstract algebra for the first time with Dummit & Foote textbook.
It is mentioned in the book that $C_G(A) \le N_G(A)$ for a group $G$ and any nonempty subset $A$ in $G$.
So I wondered whether there are subgroup /subset relations between the center $Z(G)$ and these two, and my guess is that $Z(G) \le C_G(A) \le N_G(A)$.
My proof is as follows, can anyone verify if it is correct?
I claim $Z(G) \subset N_G(A)$.
Let $g \in Z(G).$ Since $A \subset G$, for any $a \in A, a \in G$. From the definition of center, $ga=ag,$ and $gag^{-1}=a.$ Thus, for any $a \in A$, $gag^{-1}=a$ is satisfied. Therefore $g \in N_G(A)$, and $Z(G) \subset N_G(A)$.
Since $Z(G)$ is a subgroup, $Z(G) \le N_G(A).$
Thanks for any help.

From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: "A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."

I might be being too particular about it, but I think this directly shows that $Z(G)\le C_G(A)$, thus you should now prove that $C_G(A)\le N_G(A)$, which actually follows trivially.

Another way to verify this is to note that if $A\subseteq B$ then $C_G(B)\subseteq C_G(A)$. Then verify that $Z(G) = C_G(G)$.
